# Where is the BLE device user defined name stored?

Tags: windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

Does anyone know if there is a standard way to get the user defined name for a BLE device using the Windows API? Apple includes the user defined name for iOS devices in their advertisements, perhaps somewhere in the manufacturer data.

Comment: Not completely sure what you mean but Windows when advertising uses the same name that is usedfor Classic Bluetooth. It can be read with BluetoothGetRadioInfo function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothgetradioinfo)

Answer (score 0):

By user-defined I mean that the end user defined a name for the device. For example, iOS devices allow users to enter an device name such as "MyiPhone" that other iOS devices can use. This turns out to be different that the "Device Name" that may be transmitted in an advertisement or included in the Device Name characteristic in the generic access service.

So I think the user define name Apple supports ends up being in an Apple defined service/characteristic not in the advertisement or device name characteristic in the generic access service.